# Designing a website that encourages an increase in social media Likes/Followers

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, social-media, best-practice, social-interfaces

One of our goals is to increase our social media audience (likes/followers). Throughout our website we have some Facebook functionality (primarily for sharing content), but we don’t have anything to encourage our members to ‘Like Us’ / ‘Follow Us’ (except social media icons placed in the footer).

I would like to know what website design features are considered **best practice to create a user experience that encourages users to engage with us through social media within our website**.

For example, are modals or pop-ups a good tool to try and achieve this, or would they result in a negative user experience? What other options may we consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to encourage people to follow your social media is to have contents that fit your user groups.

Content strategy is always heart of social media. Most of people would follow BuzzFeed on Facebook because they have great amazing feeds. They know who their audiences are.

You might try to have a free content or contest or webinars on your Facebook and promote that on your website, to allow some excitements coming in.

I also feel that popping up a modal after user accomplished something would lead to a success. Say the user accomplished a task of buying a discounted price of a Microwave. To have a word saying that there might be other promotions on your social media and to show a 'Facebook Like' button with the number of likes right underneath it would do great.

Your copy is also important. Always give the reason why they need to click that 'Follow Us On Facebook' button. What are the benefits that they could get.

A research about "[A Power of Because](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2008/06/the-power-of-be.html)" would increase the chances of people click on that button.